# keymapping in puppy linux using bind function

Tags: linux, bind

I am using puppy linux 5.2.8 and I want to map function keys F2 and F3 according to our setup.when I press <kbd>F3</kbd> my setup file should be run. I tried bind function to bind keys. It is working properly.

```
 `bind '"\eOQ":"pwd\n"'`
```

But I want to make this changes permanently I used to put this in .xinitrc file to take effect but it is not working. How to make this effect permanent?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your trying to make this work from a prompt?  Assuming you're using bash (or any other shell that uses readline), you can put it into `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\eOQ": "pwd\n"
```

<kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+r</kbd> is supposed to re-process your `~/.inputrc`, but I've found that unreliable in the past.  So it's best to restart your shell.

If you want to limit this just to bash, you can wrap it in a conditional:

```
$if Bash
    "\eOQ": "pwd\n"
$endif
```

Comment: thanks sir.I have checked for ~/.inputrc file but it is not present.so i put it on .xinitrc file but it doesn't work .

Comment: @nilesh Create it.  `.xinitrc` is used by `startx`, it's not where you want to put this.

Comment: Thanks sir i have created the file ~/.inputrc and pste the following code :-    "\eOQ": "pwd\n"
and restarted the machine but the effect doesn't happen.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SHELL`?  Are you trying this at a terminal (xterm, konsole, gnome-terminal)?

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that you're using puppy linux.  You might need to put it in `/etc/inputrc` then.  Are you using a real shell or are you using BusyBox?

Comment: when i run the command echo $SHELL it gives output /bin/bash .I am using a real shell .

Comment: Thanks sir , I put the bind function definition "\eOQ":"pwd\n". in /etc/inputrc file and restart the system and it works....

Comment: Dear sir , I want to map a key using bind function such that it is used from anywhere.when i bind some script like                 bind  '"\eOR":"cattest\n"'
then it is executed only from terminal .I want to use from outside the terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gets to be more difficult.  You may want to look at this [answer on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/a/194203/156057) and follow some links from there.

Comment: thanks sir but i didnt find any solution there .if u gave a solution it is very thankful to me